# How Do I Get Chrome To Work When Using $('#myForm').submit() Followed By window.location.href =

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In IE and FireFox, when I run this:

```
$('#editForm').submit();

window.location.href = "my url here";
```

It works. In Chrome, both lines work on their own, but running them together means that the form is not submitted. Even sticking the submit call inside an If statement with the redirect called upon success of this If statement means that it redirects without submitting.

Comment: It shouldn't work in any browser. A pending form submission prevents the page being redirected, in all browsers. Without seeing more code, it's hard to say how to fix. A guessed quick-fix: `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the handler function.

Comment: what are you trying to achive here? that code logically makes little sensse

Comment: @Liam - Probably an annoying popup

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it like so:

```
$('#editForm').submit(function(){
    window.open('url', 'myWindow', 'target=_blank');
});
```

IMHO, a more elegant solution would be:

```
$('#editForm').submit(function(e){
    // Prevent the form from actually submiting
    e.preventDefault();
    // Code to AJAX submit (and Validate) the form goes here
    DoSomethingAjax();
    // Open a new window
    window.open('url', 'myWindow', 'target=_blank');

});
```

CodePen for the first
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgwqrE

**P.S**

A clean and elegant solution if you would like only to redirect, would be to use backend code to redirect after the form has been submitted successfully.

Comment: Why is the form submission pending? i did not stop it with `e.preventDefault()` so it will bubble and open.

Comment: I've tried that, but it then dosn't hit anything inside the function.

Comment: Please have a look at the JSFiddle i attached, it proves it works by using `console.log` instead of `window.location` probably something else is preventing the submission.
oops, my bad, bad link to jsfiddle. give me a moment.

Comment: Changed to CodePen because of an issue with JSFiddle

Comment: @Teemu - As long as it performs what the OP wanted, where is the issue? am pretty sure the OP wants to submit and open a window in the same run and not simultaneously.
If you check the Pen, you will see it works exactly as intended.

Comment: The "criticism" was for the first snippet in your answer, which originally had `window.location.href`, you've edited the answer since...

Comment: I've tried this, but it still dosn't work either. It just does nothing instead. It should work though, and probably works in a browser (such as IE or Firefox), but sadly still not in Chrome.

Comment: i am using Chrome myself and it works. (You can see it is working on the CodePen)
As i said earlier, you probably have a different issue.